# Angular js Регулярное выражение в директиве валидации вызывает ошибку Error: too much recursion

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, angularjs, angular-directive

У меня директива, проверяющая имя хоста с регулярным выражением:
/^(xn--)?(([a-zA-Z0-9]|[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*[a-zA-Z0-9])\.?)+([A-Za-z0-9]|[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9\-]*[A-Za-z0-9])*$/
когда количество символов > 25 в поле которое проверяем и дописываем любой символ, например %, браузер зависает. С буквенными символами проблем не возникает, проблемы нету также при маленьком количестве символов.
Подскажите, пожалуйста что не так.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если не ошибаюсь, вы столкнулись с явлением "Катастрофический возврат". Описание и пути решения можно посмотреть тут: https://learn.javascript.ru/regexp-catastrophic-backtracking

Возможно, прочитав, вы сами найдёте другой путь оптимизации. Могу предложить второй из предложенных там путей, просто применяю его формально, глубоко не вникая в вашу ситуацию.

Чтобы регулярка была чуть менее запутанная, я сначала попробовал её сократить: добавил флаг игнорирования регистра, чтобы можно было использовать только `a-z`, числовой диапазон заменил на `\d`.

Далее я вставил знак отмены запоминания выражений в скобках `?:`, чтобы было проще применять решение проблемы.

Наконец, окружил первую большую группу повторений предложенным заглядыванием вперёд: `(?=(группа))\1`.

Получается что-то такое:

```js
const re = /^(?:xn--)?(?=((?:(?:[a-z\d]|[a-z\d][a-z\d_-][a-z\d])\.?)+))\1(?:[a-z\d]|[a-z\d][a-z\d-][a-z\d])*$/i;

console.log(re.test('example.example.example.example.example.example.example.example.org%'));
```

Ещё мне вот что пришло в голову. Поскольку у вас очень ограниченный набор разрешённых символов, а сложность только в разных допустимых их сочетаниях, вы можете помочь движку регулярок, вставив в начало проверку с заглядыванием вперёд до конца, в которой укажите разрешённые символы: `/^(?=[\w.-]+$)дальше-ваша-регулярка/i`. Тогда многие тупиковые варианты будут отметаться с ходу:

```js
const re = /^(?=[\w.-]+$)(xn--)?(([a-z\d]|[a-z\d][a-z\d_-][a-z\d])\.?)+([a-z\d]|[a-z\d][a-z\d-][a-z\d])*$/i;

console.log(re.test('example.example.example.example.example.example.example.example.org%'));
```

Comment: Ваш ответ был очень полезен, спасибо большое,